# Hyper-v in windows 8.1 single language

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How enable Hype-v in windows 8.1 single language for emulator windows phone app ( in Windows Phone "Sdk" 8.0)

Answer (score 1):

hyper v is not available in windows 8.1 single language need to upgrade to windows 8.1 pro or use oracle vm

Comment: I have the same issue, do you know how to upgrade single language to pro. any way that i can get licence?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing Windows Phone app then surely you need Hyper-V to deploy the app over the Win Phone 8 image. But in case you are having Win 8.1 SL, you would be actually in trouble. The alternative is any other virtual tool. Here I suggest Oracle VirtualBox. After installing virtual box you have to create a machine with an OS image. For windows phone 8 or any other version goto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images". You can also go to v8.1. What I mean to say is to locate the directory for Flash.vhd. Copy the whole directory("\Images") to some other location. Start your VM and create a new machine with OS Windows 8 or 8.1 (depending upon the image version). In the next screen allocate RAM >= 1 GB. Then finally locate the Windows Phone image (Flash.vhd) after clicking "Use an existing virtual hard drive file". Click "Create" and all done!!
Another way of doing this without having any Virtual Machine is by Microsoft XDE. For this you have to start the CMD with admin rights and change the directory (CD) to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0
```

(Remember the last directory into this path could be 8.1 as well). Then run the following command

```
XDE.exe -vhd “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd”
```

Now I would suggest one more thing. Before doing all this first check where is all the stuff installed in your PC. And sorry, I have not taken care of so much formatting of this post. Enjoy :)

Comment: How to use the virtual box with visual studio? I want to run and test window app from Visual Studio and Appcelerator studio.

Comment: @Max Are you talking about creating an app and then running this on a phone image in VM? Sorry I was unable to respond you on time